# Creating a select class dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint, dynamic

I'm struggling with modifying some code I have that dynamically creates a select box based on column values from a sharepoint list.

at the moment the code:

```
function getAjaxFilter(name, internalName) {
$.ajax({
    url: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite() + '/_layouts/filter.aspx?ListId=' + listID + '&FieldInternalName=' + internalName + '&ViewId=' + viewID + '&FilterOnly=1&Filter=1' + filterFieldsParams,
    success: function(data) {

        $('#filterField' + internalName).html(name).append($("<div></div>").append(data).find("select"));
        //clear current onChange event
        $("#diidFilter" + internalName).attr("onchange", '');
        // add change event
        $("#diidFilter" + internalName).change(function() {
            FilterField(viewID, internalName, encodeURIComponent(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value), this.selectedIndex);
        });
    }
```

Creates the following html:

```
<div id="filterFieldSub_Category">
Sub Category
<select title="Filter by Sub_Category" id="diidFilterSub_Category">
    <option>(All)</option>
    <option>(Empty)</option>
    <option value="Test">Test</option>
</select>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to get it to produce a select class so I can apply it to a 3rd party selectbox styler like bootstrap select. so It needs to look like:

```
<select class="selectpicker" id= "filterFieldSub_Category">
<option>(all)</option>
<option>(empty)</option>
<option>test</option>
</select>
```

I'm not sure where to start, so if anyone could point me in the right direction that would be a huge help :)

Comment: you could add under `$("#diidFilter" + internalName).attr("onchange", '');` something like `$("#diidFilter" + internalName).removeAttr("value");`, [you can read some more about .removeAttr() here.](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) that to start, but you may want to re create the way you are creating the DOM element from the data bring with the ajax call... Can you post the data bring by it, so we can see how it is organized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the class using `addClass()` :

```
$("#diidFilter" + internalName).addClass('selectpicker');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's really helpful thank you! still not working quite right but I'm definitely getting closer :)

Edit! actually - go it working now. Thanks again!